# global-variable-exists is triggering errors in Sass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using a ternary-like statement to initialize a variable in Sass. This allows me to set some of my default variables to the same thing that Zurb Foundation is using, but if I decided to not include a Foundation module, then things should not fall on their head.

```
$nav-link-icon-color: if( global-variable-exists($topbar-link-color), $topbar-link-color, #fff) !default;
```

This was working fine until after I upgraded to Sass 3.4. Immediately after that, I started getting this error:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 20 of sass/partials/_navigation-icons.scss: $name: #ffffff is not a string for `global-variable-exists')
```

`$topbar-link-color` has been initialized when I check it. It's a string with the value #fff, declared like this by Foundation:

```
$topbar-link-color: #fff !default;
```

I even tried passing an uninitialized variable into `global-variable-exists()`:

```
$nav-link-icon-color: if( global-variable-exists($happy-scrappy), $happy-scrappy, #fff) !default;
```

But Sass still hates that too:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 21 of sass/partials/_navigation-icons.scss: Undefined variable: "$happy-scrappy".)
```

This is very odd to me, since the whole point of `global-variable-exists()` is, ya know, checking if the variable exists. It seems like the parameter sent to `global-variable-exists()` is not being parsed correctly, but I don't know.

I've tried uninstalling all versions of Sass and Compass, then reinstalling, and finally rebooting to no avail. I've even reverted back to Sass 3.3.14, which I was using before, and the same errors persist.

compass 1.0.1
Sass 3.4.0
Foundation 5.3.3
ruby 2.0.0p481
Win 7 64 bit

Edit: After further research my wrong way of doing it was working in sass 3.2.19 and compass 0.12.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "problem" persists because you're using the function incorrectly.  The [docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#global_variable_exists-instance_method) paint a very clear picture as to how this function is intended to be used:

```
$a-false-value: false;
// global-variable-exists(a-false-value) => true

.foo {
  $some-var: false;
  @if global-variable-exists(some-var) { /* false, doesn't run */ }
}
```

See how there are no variables being passed to the function?  That's because it expects a **string that contains the name of the variable**, not the variable itself.  Passing in the variable itself would defeat the purpose of the function: you can't pass variables that don't exist to functions or mixins.

So... just drop the `$`:

```
$nav-link-icon-color: if( global-variable-exists(topbar-link-color), $topbar-link-color, #fff) !default;
```

Comment: Thank you *so* much! That took care of it. You're right. I was totally overlooking the need to drop the $. It seems that my incorrect way of doing it was working serendipitously on an older combination of compass and sass.

Comment: This confused me too - I presumed they just meant to insert the variable name