# Is there an equivalent of isset or a null coalescing operator in SASS?

Tags: variables, sass, null-coalescing

I want to set a variable only if it hasn't been set.

SO...

In `_layout.scss`:

```
$page-width: 1100px;
```

However, in my `_module.scss` file, I don't want to have a dependency on `_layout.scss`

I'd like to do something like this :

```
$page-width = $page-width ?? 960px; 
// If $page-width exists, use it, otherwise set it to a default of 960px;
```

I'd like something that preferable works in SASS 3.2. I found a solution here, otherwise:

[global-variable-exists is triggering errors in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396956/global-variable-exists-is-triggering-errors-in-sass)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [variable defaults](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_), and SASS supports them. Variable defaults allow you to assign to variables if they aren't already assigned using `!` at the end of the value.

In your case, you can use this in `_layout.css`:

```
$page-width: 1100px;
```

And then in `_module.scss` you can

```
$page-width: 960px !default;
```

This is roughly equivalent to saying `assign $page-width to 960px unless $page-width is already defined`.

Check out the docs on [default variables](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_).

Comment: This is great! It can be used in conjunction with a default mixin parameter to handle both missing OR empty parameter. eg. `myMixin($offset: 10px) { $offset: 20px !default; }` so if `$offset` is not passed to the mixin then it'll get a default of 10px and if you send an empty value it'll become 20px :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mohamad's answer is the best one for your particular code example, but it's worth mentioning that the Sass `or` operator can *sometimes* be used as a drop-in replacement for the `??` operator:

```
$my-property: $uncertain-variable or $backup-value;
```

I say 'sometimes', because it's only good if your `$uncertain-variable` has been defined.

This is more reliable than some languages—*cough JavaScript*—because as the [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/boolean#truthiness-and-falsiness) point out:

> Some languages consider more values falsey than just `false` and `null`. Sass isn’t one of those languages! Empty strings, empty lists, and the number `0` are all truthy in Sass.

Whether you want to use `or` this way is a matter of personal preference I suppose. While it's very succinct, you could argue that an `@if` statement (or `if()` function) is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As of version 3.1.2, there's an `if` function, that takes three arguments; the condition to check, and two values, one of which is returned, depending on the result:

```
if(condition, value-returned-if-true, value-returned-if-false);
```

This may useful when you don't want to set up defaults elsewhere in your code.